# Tomcat 7 and CSRF filter

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, csrf, csrf-protection

I am trying to add CSRF protection to the java web application.  I have the web.xml configured with the CSRF filter and filter mappings to the servlets.
However, I am not sure how to do this next part.  the documentation says all URLs returned to the client are encoded via a call to HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL(String) or HttpServletResponse#encodeURL(String)
They also say you can try:
Or one can pass back the nonce as a request parameter with name org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE, which is the value of the constant org.apache.catalina.filters.Constants.CSRF_NONCE_REQUEST_PARAM.

**UPDATE**
I am still stuck getting a 403 forbidden. anyone have any suggestions?
Here is web.xml setup:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRF</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
      <param-value>/html,/html/</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRF</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>exampleservlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Here is the JSP page code

```
<FORM METHOD="POST"  ACTION="<%=response.encodeURL("/exampleservlet")%>">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE" VALUE="<%=session.getAttribute("org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE")%>">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="id" VALUE="0">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We are also having same issue. Anyone get the solution?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is no more important right now as the question is raised years ago, but I occasionally visit it for some hints for the usage of `org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter`.
As described on the document from tomcat official site [CSRF_Prevention_Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter), this `CsrfPreventionFilter` is assumed to be mapped to "/*", and using `init-param` named "entryPoints" to hold URLs for

> provide a way to navigate back to a protected application after having navigated away from it

I'll try to explain the work done by `CsrfPreventionFilter` in a simply way:

1. First when client access the application, the URL requested must be mapped by the filter and matching one of the `entryPoints`. So that `CsrfPreventionFilter` could **generate a new nonce** and **store into session** and **wraps the response** overriding  `HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL(String)` and `HttpServletResponse#encodeURL(String)`, while **not blocking the request(by returning 403)**.
2. URLs in the page should be encoded by `HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL(String) or HttpServletResponse#encodeURL(String)`, as you have done at the form action. As a matter of fact, the "encoding" is to append a request parameter name "org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE" with value of a nonce generated by filter in the first step.
3. When client access the URLs in the page which are encoded, `CsrfPreventionFilter` would check if the requests are valid -- whether the nonce matches one of those stored in current session (using a LRUCache with size of 5 default, can be set through the init-param `nonceCacheSize`).

So, unless the servlet `exampleservlet` you declared also mapped to "/*" or "`/html,/html/`", and /html could lead to the page holding the form, your code would not work.

Because the response you use in

> `<FORM METHOD="POST"  ACTION="<%=response.encodeURL("/exampleservlet")%>">`

is not wrapped by `CsrfPreventionFilter` and would not do the magic to append nonce.

Neither the

> `<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE" VALUE="<%=session.getAttribute("org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE")%>">`

would succeed because session attribute  "org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE" had never been set by the filter. Even there is one, it holds a LRUCache instance but not a nonce string.